# Get latest version of GitLab repo when depending on it in package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, gitlab

My private GitLab repository stores a NodeJs module (it contains *package.json* and *index.js*). In another project, I want to refer to this repository as a dependency using

```
"package-name": "git+ssh://git@gitlab01:path/to/repo#branch"
```

Where:
-  «gitlab01» is the hostname of my companies GitLab server (resolvable in my network)
- «branch» is the branch I am pushing stuff on and is supposed to
   be updateable via `npm install`.

Up until now, I can only update to a new version by using an additional tag in GitLab that I am using instead of `branch` (e.g. *v0.1.3*) that I have to replace in the *package.json* each and every time. Then I have to delete the "node_modules" folder and run `npm install` to do a clean update.

How can I achieve that the latest commit is being used by `npm install` without the need of a tag added manually every time in GitLab and changing it in the *package.json*?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [semantic versions](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver) instead branch name. To setup your "package" repo should match versions (tags) with branches, for instance:

```
git checkout branch100
npm version 1.0.0
git push
git checkout branch110
npm version 1.1.0
git push
...
git push --tags
```

Then go to your "project" and set in package.json:

```
"package-name": "git+ssh://git@gitlab01:path/to/repo#semver:>1.0.0"
```

Then:

```
npm install
```

It will install 1.1.0 version. Read carefully about semver (versions, ranges, etc)

Comment: `git version x.x.x` just returns the current version of git itself. Using `git tag x.x.x`, I can create new tags, but when pushed and referenced following your example, I get `error: pathspec 'semver:>1.0.0' did not match any file(s) known to git`

Comment: I'm sorry, it's "npm version" instead "git version" (I edited my answer). This command creates automatically tags for each branch of your git project.

Comment: `error: pathspec` still remains although branches and tags are created now as intended. `npm install` fails with error, `yarn` doesn't fail, but doesn't update either

Comment: Try "get fetch". Then for each branch/version: "git checkout branch_name", "git pull", "npm version x.x.x", "git push". And do not forget "git push --tags" at final". I just did a test and it works for me.

Comment: still nothing... 
`"vnd-types": "git+ssh://git@gitlab01:npm/vnd-types#semver:>1.0.0"`
this is my dependency. Did I miss anything? I installed `semver` as well but it didn't help

Comment: I have something like this in dependencies on package.json: "test01": "git+ssh://git@my_domain:my_username/test01.git#semver:>1.0.0". I think you are forgetting ".git".